# UIsplitviewcontroller:How to customize the uisplitview in ios

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I have to customize the uisplitview. Already i search the googling but i got the answer the splitview size is fixed. Any help? Is there any option to customize the uisplitview?